# Ajax variable issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax variable issue and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. The issue happens at the line:

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "feedback.php");
```

I reach the before alert but not the after.

```
<script>
    function toShow(elem){

        var id = elem.value;
        var x = elem.checked;

        alert("before");
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "feedback.php");
        alert("after");

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

            _("status").innerHTML = "saving to feedback DB...";
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "update_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("status").innerHTML = "it didn't work";
                } else {
                    _("status").innerHTML = "updated";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("id="+id+"&x="+x);
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas what is causing this? This same piece for code works on other pages.

here is my ajaxObj function:

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open( meth, url, true );
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}

function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ajaxObj`? Is it a function? Because you're invoking it like one.

Comment: Where is ajaxObj defined?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: i've added the ajaxObj in the post

Comment: I'm not positive, but don't you have to `x.send()` to complete the request? Sorry, I just noticed your `send()` request at the end of your original post.

Comment: This works on all my other ajax requests across my site.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kh6x5p6c/. Maybe you are testing in a browser that doesn't support `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your javascript console @RichardMoreau?

Comment: How is `toShow` triggered?

Comment: Why don't you open up the debugger (ctrl+shift+j in chrome) and see what line actually throws the error? (Go to the sources tab and click the little pause button until its blue then reload the page). Also spend some time reading up on javascript debugging with devtools. There is no reason you should be using `alert` statements here.

Comment: toShow is thiggered by an onclick event on a checkbox

Comment: found my stupid error. It was all on me. Jonathan Crowe thanks for the hint. The issue was that my feedback.php file is located in a child folder and the path for the ajax.js was wrong.

Comment: Glad you found the correct solution. No clue why you accepted my answer since it had nothing to do with the immediate problem, but do try to keep the variable names meaningful. Trust me on this one.

Comment: Akamaozu, I click it by mistake. now removed. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not a problem. Just glad your problem is solved and we all learned something :)

Answer (score 1):

I think somewhere in your scope, x is being clobbered. You use it in pretty much every function and the scope chain will silently punish you for it once you make a mistake. I can guarantee that changing those x references to meaningful names will solve this.

The problem is unlikely to be in the code block since it works most times. Something is clobbering it.

It's similar to a problem I had not too long ago: https://twitter.com/akamaozu/status/525494000288284672

That is to say ... x is being overwritten somewhere. I don't know where since it'll take a much deeper look at your code to identify where the real problem is, but change those x variables to something that actually makes sense. This will do two things:

- make your code worlds more readable
- prevent x from being hoisted

Comment: Note that what the OP does is perfectly fine as long as all declarations of `x` are either in a parameter declaration or `var` block so there's no error in the posted code. But point taken that this could be an issue.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I totally agree the problem isn't in this code sample. I double-checked it against my own and it looks like it should work. Since it works most times, the code is fine. What's happening is on certain pages, something affects this code and makes it break. The x variable is the best suspect, although status vs _('status') is another possible point of failure. That being said, the before/after alert is what made me suspect the x, since the thing that would prevent alert('after') from running has to be in function ajaxObj.